# No route found for font files in Symfony

Tags: symfony, fonts, routes, assetic

I'm struggling a bit with loading fonts in Symfony. Here's what's going wrong:

**The situation**

I am using Symfony and I am trying to add the Metro UI CSS files to a bundle. The files live in the Resources/public/lib/metro-ui folder.

```
Resources/public/lib/metro-ui
    - css
    - fonts
    - js
    - min
```

I have a layout in a twig file like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    'bundles/manager/lib/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap.css'
%}
```

Metro UI's bootstrap file contains the following fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'metroSysIcons';
  src: url('../fonts/metroSysIcons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/metroSysIcons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/metroSysIcons.svg#metroSysIcons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I used Assetic's command assets:install to install the assets into my web folder. The assets have in fact been copied, even the fonts.

**The problem**

When I go to the webpage my css is loaded, but my fonts aren't. When I look in the developer console (F12 in Chrome) I can see that loading the fonts results in a 404. The requested URL is:

```
http://sub.domain.lc/fonts/metroSysIcons.woff
```

When I type this address into my browser I get the following:

```
No route found for "GET /fonts/metroSysIcons.woff"

404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception:
ResourceNotFoundException »
```

For every other asset this just works:

```
// This loads the correct bootstrap file:
http://sub.domain.lc/css/afd9510_metro-bootstrap_1.css
```

So basically every asset can be found like this, but not my font files (woff and tff both).

**The questions**

My problem raises multiple questions:

- Why is Symfony trying to find my font through the app.php, using routes?
- Are all assets found through routes?
- If so: why are routes to font files not being resolved?
- How can I get my font files to load?

**[edit]**

I tried using the css rewrite filter like this:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    'bundles/manager/lib/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap.css'
%}
```

I am still getting a 404, but now the browser is trying to retrieve my font from this location:

```
http://sub.domain.lc/bundles/manager/lib/metro-ui/fonts/metroSysIcons.woff
```

I'm getting the same "No route found for "GET /"....." error message.

Comment: Check your `web` folder, the structure, and check if `web/bundles/manager/lib/metro-ui/fonts/metroSysIcons.woff` exists or if there are differences

Comment: It does exist and there are no differences.

Comment: Are you running the `assets:install` command?

Comment: Yes, I have used the assets:install command.

Comment: Fonts are actually being copied when I run the command assets:install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after everything I tried, there was something in my .htaccess blocking the font files.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.(?:lc|nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule $(.*) app_dev.php$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I added the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.(?:lc|nl)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|woff|tff)$
RewriteRule $(.*) app_dev.php$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now I can load fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `cssurlrewrite` filter with Assetic:

> Since Assetic generates new URLs for your assets, any relative paths
>   inside your CSS files will break. To fix this, make sure to use the
>   cssrewrite filter with your stylesheets tag. This parses your CSS
>   files and corrects the paths internally to reflect the new location.

Link to docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but it also results in a 404. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this (it kind of alias the name) :

```
{% stylesheets output = 'fonts/metroSysIcons.woff' 
    '@bundles/manager/lib/fonts/metroSysIcons.woff' %}
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I'm not sure about the line `'@bundles/manager/lib/metro-ui/css/metro-bootstrap.css'` because it could differ if your path is not exactly that one.

It should be : `@bundle_name/path/to/your/file/file.css`

And don't forget the CSS :

```
{% stylesheets '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/my.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```